# Python Selenium. winError 32 - phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying out this phantomjs to take a screenshot. It perfectly takes a screenshot and saves it. But I'm not sure why it's giving me winError 32. Sorry that some part of the console printing is in danish. I hope it may help anyway.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'PATH')
browser.get('http://www.google.com/')
browser.save_screenshot('screeniess.png')
browser.quit()
```

Console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\workspace\Python\src\afl.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser.quit()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 74, in quit
    self.service.stop()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 127, in stop
    self.send_remote_shutdown_command()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 68, in send_remote_shutdown_command
    os.remove(self._cookie_temp_file)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Processen kan ikke få adgang til filen, da den bruges af en anden proces: 'C:\\Users\\Rasmus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp_00zqu6c'
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service.Service object at 0x000001B15CDADCC0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 151, in __del__
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 127, in stop
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 68, in send_remote_shutdown_command
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Processen kan ikke få adgang til filen, da den bruges af en anden proces: 'C:\\Users\\Rasmus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp_00zqu6c'
```